# Is Linguistic search feature availabe for SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, linguistic

I am trying to use the stemming feature of Microsoft Graph connector which is a part of the Linguistic search feature. As per some Microsoft documentation, this feature is available for SharePoint onprem. But there is no mention of SharePoint online.

So my question is, is this feature available for SharePoint Online? If Yes, do you have any references?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately， as far as I know, the stemming feature of the Microsoft Graph connector is not currently available for SharePoint Online.